# oninstall vs onactivate event in ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

What is the difference between `oninstall` and `onactivate` events? When are they fired? Which event should I use in order to initialise **once-in-a-lifetime** operations such as IndexedDB and WebSocket?

Answer (score 5):

The `oninstall` event is the first one received by a Service Worker, and is intended to be used for preparatory activities such as cache and database initialization.

The `onactivate` event is fired after the `installing` stage is complete (when all the [extend lifetime promises](http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#installation-algorithm) have resolved). It is at this point that the Service Worker is fully operational, and can clean up resources that were in use by previous versions.

The `onactivate` event will be delayed until the promise passed to [`event.waitUntil(f)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#wait-until-method) resolves, if it is used. This ensures that the worker will not begin work before its dependencies are ready.

This MDN article is a useful summary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Basic_architecture

[image: A flowchart summary of a Service Worker lifecycle.]